# How to Fetch Github Repository Issues?

Tags: github, github-api

I am Having One Project repository in Github.

and i want to read all the issues.

is there any API's available for it?

Comment: http://developer.github.com/v3/issues/

Comment: It is REST, you can use it with whichever language you want. E.g http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/09/simple-rest-client-in-java.html

Comment: try [jcabi-github](http://github.jcabi.com/index.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Building up on [Emyl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1671973/emyl)'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19604845/how-to-fetch-all-github-repository-issues-using-java#comment29100481_19604845), an example of an url getting you [issues for a given repo](http://developer.github.com/v3/issues/#list-issues-for-a-repository) is:

https://api.github.com/repos/hakimel/reveal.js/issues

You can see an example in Java in the project [**GitHub API for Java**](http://github-api.kohsuke.org/), and the class [`GHIssue.java`](https://github.com/kohsuke/github-api/blob/master/src/main/java/org/kohsuke/github/GHIssue.java#L225-L227).

```java
private String getIssuesApiRoute() {
    return "/repos/"+owner.getOwnerName()+"/"+owner.getName()+"/issues/"+number;
}
```

Comment: I have tried above API's and it is giving me.